# HTMLTable: Empty link element should take up whole cell space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a (bootstrap) table where I put a link inside one of the cells, where it might happen, that the actual link text is empty, thus not showing the link element (or better to say the user can't click it). Now the goal is, that the link element should take up the whole cell space regardless of whether there is some text in the link or not.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td><a ...>Text that might be empty</a></td>
  ...
```

I have tried setting the **display** property of the a-tag to *inline-table* which worked for the most browsers except IE. Is there a nice, clean and crossbrowser compatible way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to use something like <td>&nbsp;</td> ?

Comment: `whole cell space`, what is that space, have you defined minimum space for the cell?

Comment: &nbsp; won't make the the a-element span over the entire available cell space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the anchor a `display: block`. It then will take the full width of its parent.

I've made you this demo. By clicking the button, you'll see how it works.

Note, that the anchor should at least have 'something' in it.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('a').toggleClass('block');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
tr, td {
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  background: blue; 
}
a.block {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></td>
    <td>Text<br />text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text text</td>
    <td>Text text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>Toggle block</button>
```

Comment: So I have to put something like &nbsp; in there otherwise it won't work with no content in it?

Comment: Yes, there needs to be something inside it. For you accessibility you want to have a explaining text inside it anyway (think of blind visitors)

Comment: Makes sense that argument and behaviour - the solution works for me somehow, but does not fill up the entire height, if there are other cells within the table row spanning multiple text rows

Comment: You'll need to add `tr, td { height: 100%; }`, see my edit.

Comment: Does work in Firefox, but does not work in Chrome or IE (both do only vertically align the a-element in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-width` for the column

```
<td style="min-width:50px"><a ...>Text that might be empty</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with/without text.

```
.hasLink{
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
}
.hasLink a{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0px; //if you don't want to show any text
  padding: 8px 0 0 5px;
}

<tr>
  <td class="hasLink"><a href="#"></a></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: font-size 0px won't even show the text if there is something in it.